# ics file on webcal URI scheme

Tags: asp.net, iis, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I've created an ics file using [DDay iCal library.](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/)  Now I want to make a calendar feed with it using `webcal protocol`.  If the name of the file I've created is `myCalendar.ics`, it will be accessible using:

```
webcal://localhost/myCalendar.ics
```

I have no idea how to achieve this.

Also, when I change something in the ics file, such as the event venue, does the client calendar agent (e.g. outlook, or Google calendar) pick up the modified value automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I implemented a DDay calendar based off my organizational calendar.

EDIT:
I typically provide the full URL to the .ics file and have my
clients paste this URL into the webcal address within the subscribing
client (Outlook, in my case).  I've since looked this up on the
MS site - you can automatically subscribe to the .ics by prepending
your URL with webcal:// instead of http (or webcals://, if using SSL).  See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-and-subscribe-to-internet-calendars-HA010167325.aspx#BM2).  
/EDIT

Question 2: 
Yes, the calendar client will pick up changes in the internet calendar.  Outlook, for instance, retrieves changes from the .ics file on the normal Outlook Send/Receive schedule.

Again, note that .ics calendar subscriptions are read-only.  In case you were hoping for a two-way syncing calendar, that's a whole other question...:)

Comment: thanks for the response. One way is enough for me, I want to edit the myCalendar.ics on the server, and let the client to be update automatically. So you mean that, by creating an anchor which its href is the .ics file, this subscription happens? and in case of update to myCalendar.ics, client pick the update automatically?

Comment: Actually, I just retested, since it's been a while.  To get the ics to open as a webcal in your default calendar app, you do have to prepend your link with webcal:// .  And yes, the client then picks up changes to that calendar's events  automatically.  I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @MTAdmin Do you happen to know how frewuently it checks? presumably it must be polling at regular intervals as there's no obvious push mechanism?

Comment: I believe it checks on the schedule of your subscribing application.  So in the case of Outlook (2010), it will check every time Outlook performs a Send/Receive, whether automatic or manual.  I don't know this for sure, but this is what I recall from my testing ~ 2 years ago.  I'll verify tomorrow.

Comment: @Basic - Confirmed in Outlook.  Events update with every Send/Receive performed on the client.  Also, note that if your application uses SSL, you will have to prepend your link with webcals://